# Installation error for CiviCRM in Wordpress

Tags: wordpress

I have searched for answers and none apply to this particular instance. I get one particular error preventing me from installing CiviCRM in WordPress. I have the latest version of CiviCRM and WordPress. I get the following error under file permissions no matter what I do:

**Is the /home/tackletheagenda/public_html/Civicrm/wp-content/plugins/files folder writeable?**

**The user account used by your web-server - tackletheagenda - needs to be granted write access to the following directory in order to configure the CiviCRM settings file:
//home/tackletheagenda/public_html/Civicrm/wp-content/plugins/files**

I have already verified that the folders were writable. A bug? Other people had this problem on other platforms, but no answers for this problem in WordPress.

Comment: It seems there may be a problem with the path of your civicrm installation.  My working civicrm installation in Wordpress is in the equivalent of your account at /public_html/wp-content/plugins/civicrm.  In that directory, there should be a properly configured file called civicrm.settings.php.  There should also be a directory called "files" in /wp-content/plugins which should have been created during the installation.

Comment: Full installation info is at this link https://wiki.civicrm.org/confluence/display/CRMDOC/Installing+CiviCRM+for+Wordpress and also here at https://docs.civicrm.org/sysadmin/en/latest/install/wordpress/

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

The link that is supposed to provide a solution for this is broken...on this page:

https://docs.civicrm.org/sysadmin/en/latest/install/wordpress/

If you are on a Windows machine and get the message "The user account used by your web-server needs to be granted write access to the following directory in order to configure the CiviCRM settings file: C:/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/" even after changing directory permission in 
Explorer, see:

http://forum.civicrm.org/index.php/topic,5056.msg23720.html#msg23720

Answer (score 0):

Did you verify the directories were writable by testing using php - or checking the permissions? To definitively confirm this is a civicrm bug perhaps put something similar to the below in a file in your web root then visit it in your browser. (Don't forget to remove the file afterwards) Check if the file was created. If it was then this is a civicrm issue - however if not it is a permissions issue.

```
<?php
file_put_contents("/home/tackletheagenda/public_html/Civicrm/wp-content/plugins/files/test.txt", 'Test');
?>
```

If it is a permissions issue double check the permission of the parent directories to make sure the web user has execute access to all parent directories

```
namei -l  /home/tackletheagenda/public_html/Civicrm/wp-content/plugins/files
```

Will show you all parent directories up to / along with their permissions.